# Is it taboo to take the standard deviation of a very small list of numbers?

Tags: inference, standard-deviation, intuition

I read through a similar question: [Is it meaningful to calculate standard deviation of two numbers?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230171/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-standard-deviation-of-two-numbers) However, this was largely focusing on error bars.

If I have five numbers, let's say:

```
[22.8, 31, 38.5, 48.9, 38.2]
```

The standard deviation comes out to: `9.7`

Maybe there is nothing wrong with this in theory. I can't speak to common practice about summary statistics like this in a 5 observation data set, but I know that more sophisticated things like regressions are really not taken seriously unless there is a meaningful amount of `n` (maybe several hundred or so).

**Application:** the target audience is math-educated, not necessarily stats wizards though. We are not trying to tackle anything really cerebral, computing standard deviation for this is just a way to show the spread in a concise way. However, even though we are humble, I still fear there could be backlash for using this, almost inviting criticism on our whole research. Just want to make sure we are not committing any taboos.

### Question

Would this computation irk the statistically enlightened group? Why/why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important reason for finding the sample standard deviation $S$ is that $S$ is an estimate of the population standard deviation $\sigma.$ For larger $n$ the estimate is more precise. Confidence intervals can help to give an idea of the precision.

Suppose you are sampling from a normal distribution with standard deviation $\sigma = 5.$
I will show you the *method* for finding a confidence interval for $\sigma$ based on a sample (because it's no secret), but for purposes of this answer the point is the *length* of the resulting confidence interval. (You can skip the 'Method' section if it gives more technical detail than you want.)

***Method:*** One can show that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1),$ the chi-squared distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. From that distribution I can find boundaries $L$ and $U$ with $P\left(L < \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} < U\right) = 0.95.$ By manipulating inequalities, this becomes
$P\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U} < \sigma^2 < \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right) = 0.95.$ and
$P\left(S\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{U}} < \sigma < S\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{L}}\right) = 0.95.$
Finally, we say that $\left(S\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{U}}. S\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{L}}\right)$
is a 95% confidence interval for $\sigma.$ Roughly speaking, this means that for 05% of samples this interval includes $\sigma.$

***Computation:*** Suppose I have sample standard deviations $S$ for two samples
from a normal population with mean $\sigma = 7.$ The first sample is of size $n=10$ and the second is of size $n = 100.$ Below are simulated samples and their respective confidence intervals, using R statistical software.

*Size 10:*  $S = 7.25.$ The 95% confidence interval is $(4.99, 13.24)$ of length $9.25.$

```
set.seed(330)
s = sd(rnorm(10, 50, 7));  s
[1] 7.252305
CI = sqrt(9*s^2/qchisq(c(.975,.025),9))
CI;  diff(CI)
[1]  4.988391 13.239882   # CI
[1] 8.251491              # length of CI
```

*Size 100:* $S = 7.20.$ The 95% confidence interval is $(6.32, 8.36)$ of length $2.04.$

```
set.seed(331)
s = sd(rnorm(100, 50, 7));  s
[1] 7.200381
CI = sqrt(99*s^2/qchisq(c(.975,.025),99))
CI;  diff(CI)
[1] 6.321984 8.364505
[1] 2.042521
```

And just for illustration, without showing the computations, with $n = 2,$ I got $S = 3.34,$ giving a confidence interval $(1.49, 106.60)$ of length $105.11.$
The confidence interval does include $\sigma = 7,$ but it is too long to be of
any practical use.

I wouldn't say that your readers would be 'irked' if you
give a sample standard deviation for a sample of size $n = 2,$ but they might
wonder why you bothered to report it. (Maybe it's better just to give the two values.)

Finally, there is *another difficulty* with sample standard deviations based on
samples of only two observations. they are seriously biased downward as estimates of $\sigma.$
On average, $S$ based on two normal observations will have the value
$0.798\sigma.$ That is $E(S) \approx 0.798\sigma.$ [It is always true, for all $n,$ that $E(S) < \sigma,$ but for $n$ as large as 10, the downward
bias is seldom of practical importance, and the bias becomes truly negligible for large $n.]$

Comment: Thanks, so for n=5, the bias is still a potential concern, if I understand your explanation correctly.

Comment: Depends on how fussy you are: For $n=5,$ its $E(S) \approx 0.94\sigma.$ Also $E(S^2) = \sigma^2.$ But expectation is a linear operator and so equality doesn't survive taking square roots.

Comment: More [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/why-is-sample-standard-deviation-a-biased-estimator-of-sigma).